# PHPUnit - using assertions in external object

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm working on a tool exporting tests as PHP/PHPUnit and I'm facing a small problem. To explain briefly, the test scripts only contain calls to an actionwords object, which contains all the logic of the test (in order to factors various steps from different test scenario).
An example might be clearer:

```
require_once('Actionwords.php');

class CoffeeMachineHiptestPublisherSampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  public $actionwords = new Actionwords();


  public function simpleUse() {
    $this->actionwords->iStartTheCoffeeMachine();
    $this->actionwords->iTakeACoffee();
    $this->actionwords->coffeeShouldBeServed();
  }
}
```

Here in the `coffeeShouldBeServed` method, I need to run an assertion, but that's not possible as the Actionwords class does not extend `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` (and I'm not sure it should, it's not a test case, just a set of helpers).

Currently the solution I found is to pass the tests object to the action words and use the reference for the assertions, something like that.

```
class CoffeeMachineHiptestPublisherSampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  public $actionwords;

  public function setUp() {
    $this->actionwords = new Actionwords($this);
  }
}

class Actionwords {
  var $tests;

  function __construct($tests) {
    $this->tests = $tests;
  }

  public function coffeeShouldBeServed() {
    $this->tests->assertTrue($this->sut->coffeeServed);
  }
}
```

It works fine but I don't find it really elegant. I'm not a PHP developer so there might be some better solutions that feel more "php-ish".

Thanks in advance,
Vincent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion methods are static so you can use `PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertEquals()`, for instance.

Comment: Perfect, I should have checked that before. All the examples were using $this->assertSomething so I thought I had to be in a test class